# Which of the following CANNOT be the possible number of boys and girls in the class?

Tags: fractions, ratio

The ratio boys to girls is 5/4. If a few boys leave the class, the ratio boys to would become the reciprocal of the earlier ratio. Which of the following CANNOT be the possible number of boys and girls in the class?

a) 45

b) 90

c) 120

d) 135

I know we have 9 parts, but what to do next?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "$9$ parts", but it suffices to argue that the total number must be divisible by $9$.

Comment: The second part of your question seems incomplete( the ratio of boys to ?)

Answer (score 3):

**The impossible answer is $120$**

Boys ratio and girls ratio are $\frac{5}{9}$and $\frac{4}{9}$, respectively

Any of these two fractions of $120$ are not an integer.